# VBA comma separated data in column B concatenated with text in column A

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA script that comma separates data in a cell into individual rows, e.g. if cell A1 contains the data "A,B,C,D" then this script will separate this data so A is on one row, B on the next, etc. (in a designated destination).

I am trying to update this script so the value in the cell before the comma separated data is concatenated with each new row, i.e if cell A1 contains "Test" and cell B1 contains "A,B,C,D" then the output rows should be "TestA", then "TestB" for the next row, etc.

I am stuck as to how to proceed here with this task, any input whatsoever would be beneficial, my VBA skills are not great.

```
Sub SplitAll()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRg1 As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim xAddress As String
Dim xUpdate As Boolean
Dim xRet As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg  = Application.InputBox("Please select a range", "Kutools for Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
Set xRg  = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "You can't select multiple columns", , "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
        End If
        Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Split to (single cell):", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
        Set xRg1 = xRg1.Range("A1")
        If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For Each xCell In xRg
                xRet = Split(xCell.Value, ",")
                xRg1.Worksheet.Range(xRg1.Offset(I, 0), xRg1.Offset(I + UBound(xRet, 1), 0)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xRet)
                I = I + UBound(xRet, 1) + 1
            Next
            Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way though you will need to adapt to add in your prompting a user to select a range etc.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, k As Long, tempArr() As String, outputArr(), counter As Long
    ReDim outputArr(0 To 100000)                 '<size to something larger than may be expected
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("A1:B2").Value              '<==prompt for range input instead here
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            tempArr = Split(arr(i, 2), ",")
            For k = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr)
                outputArr(counter) = arr(i, 1) & tempArr(k)
                counter = counter + 1
            Next
        Next
        ReDim Preserve outputArr(0 To counter - 1)
        .Range("C1").Resize(UBound(outputArr) + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It should do the work:

```
Sub SplitAll()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRg1 As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim yCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim xAddress As String
Dim xUpdate As Boolean
Dim xRet As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a range", "Kutools for Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "You can't select multiple columns", , "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
        End If
        Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Split to (single cell):", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
        Set xRg1 = xRg1.Range("A1")
        If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For Each xCell In xRg
                xRet = Split(xCell.Value, ",")
                xRg1.Worksheet.Range(xRg1.Offset(I, 0), xRg1.Offset(I + UBound(xRet, 1), 0)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xRet)
                For Each yCell In xRg1.Worksheet.Range(xRg1.Offset(I, 0), xRg1.Offset(I + UBound(xRet, 1), 0))
                    yCell.Value = yCell.Value & xCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                Next yCell
                I = I + UBound(xRet, 1) + 1
            Next
            Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to have empty rows in selection, after your data or inbetween rows, add this `If Not UBound(xRet, 1) = -1 Then` a line above `For Each yCell...` and add `End If` below the `Next yCell`. It's because xRet's dimension is (0 to -1) when xCell.Value is an empty string (`xRet = Split(xCell.Value, ",")` ) so it gets messy. That solves it. :)